# Minimizing and aggregating a multi-level dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion

Given a multi-level dictionary (#levels are unknown beforehand), I want to modify this dictionary to be no more than 3 level.

For example, below you can see a 5 level dictionary as an input:

```
{ K11:
     {K21:
         { K31: 
               { K41: VAL41, 
                 K42: VAL42 
              },
           K32: VAL32,
           K33: 
               {K43:
                    {K51:V51}
               }
          }
     }
}
```

The desired output is the following 3 level dict:

```
{ K11:
     {K21:
         { K31.K41: VAL41,
           K31.K42: VAL42,
           K32: VAL32,
           K33.K43.K51: V51
          }
     }
}
```

Basically starting from level 4+, I want to combine the keys all together and assign them at level 3 (Lets assume that combinations of these keys are always unique ...)

Any idea how to implement such method? I'm trying to implement a recursive function that will keep digging to last level, and then somehow to rebuild the dictionary backwards - however so far no success.

I'll appreciate if you can share your thoughts, thanks!

Comment: If possible can you please share what you tried so far ? In that case, anyone will be able to help you much quickly

Answer (score 1):

Try using json_normalize in pandas like this

```
from pandas import json_normalize

d = {'K11':
     {'K21':
         {'K31':
          {'K41': 'VAL41',
           'K42': 'VAL42'
           },
          'K32': 'VAL32',
         'K33':
          {'K43':
           {'K51': 'V51'}
           }
          }
      }
     }

print(json_normalize(d['K11']['K21'], max_level=2).to_dict('records'))
```